# Writing this statement with quantifiers

Tags: logic, quantifiers

Consider the statement "There is a math class that every first-year student is taking". Let $x$ represent a student and $y$ a class. Let $A(y)$ be "y is a math class", $F(x)$ be "x is a first-year student" and $T(x, y)$ be $x$ is taking class $y$. Consider the universe of all student and classes. I know that the statement can be written as $$ \exists y \forall x: A(y) \wedge(F(x) \rightarrow  T(x, y)).$$
Why I cannot write it as  $ \exists y \forall x: A(y) \wedge F(x)  \wedge T(x, y)$?

Comment: @GregMartin What do you mean by $x$ can be anything in the world? OP is just saying that $x$ represents a student, aren't they?

Comment: @Keio203 I find the statement hard to understand. The statement says "Let $x$ be all the students," which sounds fine at first, but then sounds weird when it says "Let $A(x)$ be '$x$ is a math class'" and "$F(x)$ be '$x$ is a first-year student.'" Do you mean "$A(x)$ means $x$ is in a math class" and "$F(x)$ means $x$ is a first-year student"? If yes then it'd make sense to say, "Let $x$ represent a student," not all the students.

Comment: @Accelerator: Thanks for pointing that out. I think I fixed it.

Comment: If there is a second-year student in existence who isn't taking that universal-first-year math class, then the first version will be true but the second version will be false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\exists y \forall x \Big(A(y) \wedge F(x)  \wedge T(x, y)\Big)\tag1$$ logically implies $$\forall x F(x),\tag2$$ that is, that every object in the universe is a first-year student.

Since the given statement does not imply sentence $(2),$ its formalisation cannot be sentence $(1).$

Answer (score 0):

The two statements you have in symbolic form aren't logically equivalent. If we're supposing $$\exists y \forall x: A(y) \wedge(F(x) \rightarrow  T(x, y))$$ is true, then the equivalent statement is $$\exists y \forall x: A(y) \wedge (\neg F(x) \vee  T(x, y)).$$

Generally speaking, $P \implies Q$ is equivalent to $\neg P \vee Q$, and you can verify that using truth tables.